# Google Geolocation API warning

Tags: curl, geolocation

I'm trying the curl command they provided in the documentation and it says(in bold) that is not able to read data from file which I named sample_geolocate.json.  It's providing me a location but it's not really close, which I changed to lat and long, but it's not accurate  Any idea why is not able to read the file?

```
C:\Users\ferna>curl -d @sample_geolocate.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyAmDKuFgCXdea2kPgyZlO3hWWDzVE0-Z0o"
**Warning: Couldn't read data from file "sample_geolocate.json", this makes an
Warning: empty POST.**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2023 17:27:17 GMT
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "location": {
    "lat": lat,
    "lng": long
  },
  "accuracy": 1996.6125299760067
}
```

I just want to get the location info (GPS Coordinates)

Comment: Do check the file it's complaining about, it's either not there, empty, or has the wrong content.